# How can I download a torrent with my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, data-transfer, torrent

I have a torrent file ([example](https://archive.org/download/meetingqa-main-2023-07-28/meetingqa-main-2023-07-28_archive.torrent)). How can  I download its content on my iPhone 12 (iOS 15, not jailbroken)?

When looking at the Apple app store, I can't find my torrent clients that I typically use on Android/Ubuntu/Windows.

I don't want to pay for a seedbox or some other [third-part downloader](https://www.torrentsafe.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [iTorrent](https://github.com/XITRIX/iTorrent)

> [image: iPhone screenshots of iTorrent]

iTorrent is a free open-source torrent client for iOS. Install via:

- compiling and installing from source with Xcode and a free Apple Developer account,
- installing the latest build on device from Microsoft App Center: https://install.appcenter.ms/users/x1trix/apps/itorrent/distribution_groups/public
- or the latest release downloaded from GitHub
  https://github.com/XITRIX/iTorrent/releases/latest
  and sideloaded with something like [AltStore](https://altstore.io/).

Answer (score 1):

Torrent clients are in conflict with section 5.2.3 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#legal) (**Audio/Video Downloading: Apps should not facilitate illegal file sharing**), so there can't be any apps in the store which would be able to download torrents.

Example of source supporting the comment: https://www.engadget.com/2009-05-11-apple-rejects-bittorrent-control-app-from-app-store-because-it-m.html